# Classify list items in different listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

My first question so I hope it makes sense :)

I have a `List<movies>` in which I store movie titles and an int grade from 1 to 5.

I would like to have 5 different listbox in a form, one for each grade, in which the titles of the movies appear depending on their grade.

How could I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Create 5 listbox, loop over your list and examine each entry, then decide in which listbox you want to insert the movie title. Try it and then ask if you have any problem with your code.

Comment: create a class containing the "movie title" and "grade" and add elements of this class to a list now you can split them up by their grades

Comment: This is a little too broad for Stack Overflow I'm afraid. But either loop over the list and decide which listbox to add to or filter this list 5 different ways.

Comment: Show us your `movies` class.  Consider using [Group By](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) to get separate lists for each ListBox?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I've got question correctly, but from the first look it's just simple where/select combination

```cs
listbox1.Items = MoviesList.Where(x => x.Rate == 1).Select(x => new ListItem(x.Name));
```